# AngularFire2 - How to get Auth User Email?

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2

how can i get currently Auth User email? Ofc it's so easy to get his uID, by

```
constructor(public af: AngularFire){
           this.user = this.af.auth.getAuth().uid;
}
```

But I cannot get his Email. How can i get this? In getAuth() method i can get uId and provider number.

Comment: try `this.af.auth.getAuth().auth.email`

Comment: Oh my god.. Thank you so much.. <3

Comment: One more question. Can i createUser not only by his Email and Password? I want to be there also Name and Surname.

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm not really familiar with firebase, I just use it to authenticate users. I do have a method to break apart the `displayName` into firstname and lastname. I could post the code in an answer if you'd like? (improved formatting, method is quite long)

Comment: World be nice ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the `email` property you will first need to access the `auth` property. (since `getAuth()` will return `{auth { .... }}` if you json it.

To convert a `auth.displayName` I myself use the following method. It will take a `string` holding 1 or more words. If there is only 1 word, it will set it to be the `lastname` with an empty `firstname`. On 2 or more words, the first word will be the `firstname` and everything after the `lastname` (with some more logic since the `string` is splitted on whitespace, and trailing whitespace looks better for a long `lastname`)

In the method itself I explain how '[Edwin van der Sar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_van_der_Sar)' would be handled.

```
// Participant = {id: number, firstname: string, lastname: string}
    private splitName(part: Participant, fullname: String): Participant {
            // split the name by space (first last) (['Edwin','van','der','Sar']);
            let splittedName:Array<string> = fullname.split(' ');

            // if only one word is displayed (f.e. ivaro18) set it as lastname 
            // (improves search results later on)
            if(splittedName.length < 2) {
                part.lastname = splittedName[0];
            }
            // if first and last name are displayed
            else if (splittedName.length < 3) {
                part.firstname = splittedName[0];
                part.lastname = splittedName[1];
            }
            // if the user has a hard name
            else if (splittedName.length >= 3) {
                // first part will be the firstname (f.e. 'Edwin')
                part.firstname = splittedName[0];
                // loop through all other and concat them to be the lastname
                for(var i = 1; i < (splittedName.length); i++){
                    if(part.lastname != undefined){
                        // first part is already there, if it isnt the last part add a space ('der ')
                        if(!(i == (splittedName.length -1))) {
                            part.lastname += splittedName[i] +" ";
                        } else {
                            // it's the last part, don't add a space ('Sar')
                            part.lastname += splittedName[i];
                        }
                    }
                    // first part of the lastname ('van ')
                    else {
                        part.lastname = splittedName[i] +" ";
                    }

                }
            }
            return part;
    }
```

*(quite possible can be improved but it's not slow at all so it's not one of my priorites)*

Comment: Please, don't hate me, but.. how can i actually create this user? I have method like this http://pastebin.com/eBFwusbk.

Comment: Don't worry haha. But I do not know the answer, I only use `angularfire2` for authenticating and retrieving the name/email from social media. I do not use email password login

Comment: No problem man, love to help. You should consider asking it in a new question if it's important to you